# JavaScript attr('id') and this

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm not really good in JavaScript, but here's something I'm kind of stuck with:

So, I got this:

```
$(".post-click").click(function()
{
var classid = $(this).attr('id');
var postid = $(this).attr('id');
postid = postid.replace('post-click-id_', '');

alert("ID: " + classid + " PostID: " + postid);

$(this).replaceWith('<img SRC="assets/img/refresh.gif" ALT="" >');

$.post("likepost.php", { postid: postid } , function(data)
{
    if(data.indexOf("Yes") >= 0)
    {
        //Question is about this part
    }
    else
    {
        //Question is about this part
    }

});
});
```

Now, at that "Yes" or else part: How can I do it so I can replace the data from `$(this)` with `replaceWith`? I thought I could do it with `classid`, but I'm not really sure how to do that. I thought about this:

```
$(classid).replaceWith('Yes, yes indeed.');
$(classid).replaceWith('Nope.');
```

How would I make this work?

Comment: For these types of questions it helps enormously if you create a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I've understood the question correctly and you're attempting to replace the clicked element inside the `$.post` callback, the easiest thing to do will be to maintain a reference to that element outside of the callback. This saves you from having to traverse the DOM again to reselect an element you have already selected once:

```
var clicked = $(this);
$.post("likepost.php", { postid: postid } , function(data) {
    if(data.indexOf("Yes") >= 0) {
        clicked.replaceWith("Yes");
    } else {
        clicked.replaceWith("No");
    }
});
```

Your current attempt doesn't work because `classid` is simply a string representing the value of the `id` attribute. To create a jQuery object from it, you would need to append it to a "#" to produce a valid selector.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ids to find the element you just have (like `$("#"+$(this).attr('id'))`), but use it directly: `$(this)`. As the [`this` reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) changes from function invocation to function invocation (it's different in your ajax callback), you will need to cache it in a variable.

```
$(".post-click").click(function() {
    var loadImg = $('<img SRC="assets/img/refresh.gif" ALT="" >');
    $(this).replaceWith(loadImg);

    var toReplace = loadImg; // could be $(this) if you hadn't replaced it already

    $.post("likepost.php", { postid: postid } , function(data) {
        toReplace.replaceWith( data.indexOf("Yes") >= 0
           ? "success"
           : "failed"
        );
    });
});
```